# mysql_query INSERT in to table where

Tags: mysql, insert

I want to insert into a table where user id = to something
And change o to 1 which means user is online

Tried this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `20s` VALUES('','','','','','','',1) WHERE `uid`='$user_id ");
```

But that doesn't get me anywhere. What's the right syntax?

Also what's the best way to keep a record of online friends in the database?

**TIP:it's better to use update here**

Comment: You probably want `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: is the code's syntax right?

Comment: I am not sure 20s is a valid table name

Comment: it works fine with login & register

Comment: 2 ideas for storing the records of online friends are: keep a JSON string/array of ids of friends and link it to the id/name of the account or have a table that tie 2 ids together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for insert query is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

but you need here is update query, so you may update already existing row:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

You only need to change one column bit that show online so dont change other columns:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `columnForOnline`=1 WHERE user_id=online_user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `WHERE` clause in `INSERT` statements ([see MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)).

If you want to update a value in an existing row, use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE `20s` SET `online`=1 WHERE user_id=your_user_id
```

<sup>`mysql_` functions are deprecated, use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/mysqli) instead!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

MySQL also supports [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), which follows the same syntax as `INSERT`. Be careful though, columns that you do not supply will be set to their defaults.

In your case:

```
REPLACE INTO `20s` VALUES('','','','','','','',1) WHERE `uid`= '$user_id'
```

(Plus, you are missing a closing quote `'` at the end of your query)

Answer (score 0):

Use `update` query instead of `insert`

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `columnForOnline`=1 WHERE user_id=online_user_id
```